# Can't get .offset() method to work when iterating over a set of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset

Essentially, I'm trying to apply a tooltip-like popup on click to a set of list items. Everything seems to be working fine except the positioning of the popup. I'm trying to use `.offset()` to grab the coordinates of each list item so that I can position the popup div relative to the list item. I've included the pertinent html elements, css and my script below. Any help would be much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="checked" title="This is a test popup message">Yada yada yada</li>
    <li class="checked" title="This is another test popup message">Yada yada yada</li>
    <li class="checked" title="This is yet another test popup message">Yada yada yada</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    z-index: 10000;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

activatePopup = function() {
    var popupMarkup = '<div class="popup">' + '</div>';
    return popupMarkup;
}

$('body').prepend(activatePopup());

$('.checked').each(function() {
    // Sets popup text based on title attribute
    var popup = $('.popup');
    var popupText = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).attr('title', '');

    //Grabs Position data of trigger element
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    var posTop = pos.top;
    var posLeft = pos.left;


    $(this).click(function() {
        popup.html(popupText);
        if (popup.is(":hidden")) {
            popup.fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            popup.fadeOut('fast');
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('unchecked');
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');

        setPos(posTop, posLeft);
    });

    setPos = function(top, left) {
        var yPos = (top - 80) + 'px';
        var xPos = (left + 40) + 'px';

        popup.css({'top' : yPos, 'left' : xPos});
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What are the offset values you are getting? It seems to be working fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: if you are doing a tool-tip it's better to use mouse position than element's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try including

```
//Grabs Position data of trigger element
var pos = $(this).offset();
var posTop = pos.top;
var posLeft = pos.left;
```

inside you `click` function like:

```
   $(this).click(function() {
        var pos = $(this).offset();
        var posTop = pos.top;
        var posLeft = pos.left;

        popup.html(popupText);
        if (popup.is(":hidden")) {
            popup.fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            popup.fadeOut('fast');
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('unchecked');
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');

        setPos(posTop, posLeft);
    });
```

this should do it :)

Comment: Argh! Rookie mistake. Thank you so much!